# How do I create objects of another class in a different class in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a class called User and a class called Record. I would like class Record to be able to instantiate a number of User instances (like 50). I'm not sure to handle this the correct way.

- Should I use inheritance and instantiate objects in the **init** of the Record class? or just create a method in Record class that creates them? ?
- How do I pass the objects values in this case? into the Record class?

I appreciate any help, Thank you in advance.

```
class User:
def __init__(self):
    pass

def retreive_user_data(self):
    url = "https://randomuser.me/api/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.text
    parsed = json.loads(data)
    return parsed

def fetch_retreived_data(self):
    response = self.retreive_user_data()
    response = response["results"][0]

    # Extracting wanted values and storing them in a dict
    data = {}
    data["uuid"] = response["login"]["uuid"]
    data["first_name"] = response["name"]["first"]
    data["last_name"] = response["name"]["last"]
    data["gender"] = response["gender"]
    data["date_of_birth"] = response["registered"]["date"]
    return data



instance = User()


class Record(User):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def CreateUser(self):
        user = User()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use inheritance, use encapsulation. In other words, place the `User` instances as attributes of your `Record` class, for example:

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.users = []

    def create_user(self) -> None:
        self.users.append(User())

    def create_multiple_users(self, n_users: int) -> None:
        for _ in range(n_users):
            self.create_user()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Record():
def __init__(self):
    myUser = createUser()
def CreateUser(self):
    return User()
```

No need to inherit.